# What is NAS with regard to a blank internal HD

Tags: hard-drive, nas

I understand Network-attached storage, but what does that have to to with blank internal hard-drives?

> **Exclusive NASware 2.0 technology** 
>   - Our exclusive technology, NASware 2.0, makes WD Red thrive in the demanding small-NAS environment. By adding WD Red to your NAS system,
>   not only is everything more efficient and reliable, you get to enjoy a
>   REDvolutionary NAS experience.

What does that mean? And in general what, if anything, do hardware manufacturers do to blank internal drives to make them better at NASing (and does this adversely effect their use as non-NAS drives)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that drives are built better than average desktop drives. WD upgraded their desktop drive and called it NAS drive to charge more money. I don't think you will run into any issues by using it in a desktop.

Comment: OK, sounds good then.

And you believe that this claim that it is just all round "better" is not just a marketing ploy, it is actually measurably better than a average non-NAS drive.

Answer (score 1):

As for WD Red, I believe it's certified for 24/7 operation and it has a bigger MTBF. However, to me it's considerably slower than WD Blue. So it's kind of more durable WD Green.

Comment: Overly jargony, but I understood some of that.

And I looked it up spindle speed: "Intellipower" basically means quite slow (5000, or maybe a little more). But this is just going to be a storage drive, so I am OK with that.

Comment: Yeah I like Red and Green for storage too. They are quiet and cold.